# How to make the skin of the body harden?

Tags: bodybuilding, skin

2 years I have been doing bodybuilding but my body skin has not become harden! Some say that a sunburn under the sun will make your skin harden but I don’t want to turn my white skin on black! Are there any recommendations on how to make your skin harden? Thank you in advance!

Comment: uhm...are you asking about skin all over? Or are you referring to calluses on your hands?

Comment: all over @JohnP

Comment: It's genetic. Unless both your parents were rhinoceroses, you're unlikely to have thick, hard skin.

Answer (score 1):

In general, your skin will only harden if it is used in that way (e.g.: you need to walk barefoot in order to have more resistant skin on your feet). Thus, the general answer to the general question is twofold:

- if your skin didn't harden after two years, it probably doesn't need to
- if you want your skin to harden regardless, you will need to use your body accordingly.

That being said: hardening your skin *in general* seems both impossible and a bad idea: the skin is designed to be flexible. But if you're specifically talking about, say, the hands or the knuckles, I can recommend doing specific exercises to slowly make your skin used to requirement of hardening. (E.g. for the latter: knuckle push-ups with decreasing layers of cloth between your hands and the floor.)